# What is wrong in this command about grepping and pandocing?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, latex

I am thinking this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247003/13173) which returns a broken PDF document in OSX 10.10.3.

The file test_dummy.tex is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wl52pqk0uw5wp4/test_dummy.tex?dl=0).

```
pandoc test_dummy.tex -f markdown -t html | grep -E '(^<|^$|^ *$)' \
| grep -v "^<p" | pandoc -f html -o tables.pdf
```

where pandoc 1.13.2.1 and grep `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`.

## 1 Mistake in test_dummy.tex -file (different than you having real LaTeX)

I installed Pandoc by `brew install pandoc`.
Something is wrong in the very beginning command

```
pandoc test_dummy.tex -f markdown -t html
```

returns a blank line, likewise `pandoc test_dummy.tex -f markdown`.

[fixed by the [answer]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/188825/15504)

## 2 Connecting the full command still challenge

The command (with cabal Pandoc)

```
pandoc test_dummy.tex -f markdown -t html | grep -E '(^<|^$|^ *$)' | grep -v "^<p" | pandoc -f html -o tables.pdf
```

returns

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:≤ not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

                                                  
l.134 ≤
```

[fixed the [addition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247003/13173) of this answer solves this part]

How can I troubleshoot this chain of commands?

Comment: I've tested this command on OSX Mavericks 10.9.5. My Pandoc is `v1.13.2.1`, installed via `cabal-install pandoc` (but usually I install the MacPorts stuff,not the HomeBrew-ed one).

Comment: The command you listed doesn't work with just pandoc installed. You've not documented the minimum tools needed to reproduce this issue. Also, if you can specify what is broken about the pdf if you in fact don't get an empty line from the first half of the command. On 10.10 - I get everything to work except the missing `pdflatex` part that fails at the second invocation of `pandoc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a blank line from `pandoc` then something is quite amiss.

My guess is you've got several `pandoc or the tex file is encoded oddly or throwing some error that the version I downloaded from dropbox isn't the same as the one you are using.

```
$ pandoc test_dummy.tex -f markdown -t html | wc 
     311    1349   11676
$ pandoc test_dummy.tex -f markdown -t html | head

<p>everything - etiology, symptoms, diagnostic tests, grades of aortic valve stenosis</p>
<p>Aortic regurgitation. The murmur of aortic regurgitation occurs during diastole as the aortic valve fails to lose completely and blood regurgitates from the aorta back into the LV. Murmur - high-pitched decrescendo murmur heard best along left lower sternal border.</p>
<table>
<caption>Common causes of Aortic Stenosis Among Patients requiring Surgery. % http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/150638-overview#aw2aab6b2b4aa</caption>
<colgroup>
<col width="38%" />
<col width="38%" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
$ which pandoc
/usr/local/bin/pandoc
$ wc test_dummy.tex 
     210    1049    8801 test_dummy.tex
```

The troubleshooting would be to check the path to be sure you are using the tools you expect. Then break apart the chain of commands and inspect the beginnings of each output file using things like `wc`, `head` or `more` so you can make sure each link in the chain is working. The post you linked to is an [exceptional answer by Kurt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247003) in that it explains exactly what the command line tools are doing with grep and why.

Comment: The command `pandoc test_dummy.tex -f markdown -t html | wc` gives me now the same as `311    1349   11676`. Output of `pandoc test_dummy.tex -f markdown -t html | head` is the same now as with you. Same test_dummy.tex file too. My pandoc is now the variant of $HOME/.cabal/bin/pandoc. Do you get the correct PDF output? Please, see my edit in the question body about the error which I get when I run the full command.